# Guzzle request does not return full response

Tags: laravel, api, guzzle

I am using Guzzle 7.0.1 Client and trying to fetch data from external API using the GET method. The endpoint does not require any extra parameters except Accept header.

```
$response = $client->request('GET', $url, [
            'headers' => [
                'Accept' => 'application/json'
            ],
            'read_timeout' => 10,
            'stream' => true
        ]);
```

Problem is when I get the response...

With Postman I am getting 11500 rows and also with `$response->getBody()->getSize()` I am getting integer with size of body 11500.

When I get the content of the body (`$response->getBody()->getContents()`) and when I decode it, response has only 617 rows. What could cause such behaviour?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is the content-length in header, you can use this `$response->getHeader('Content-Length')[0];` or use `$response->getHeaderLine('Content-Length')`

Comment: what about using [sink](https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#sink) or [stream](https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#stream)